# Shared Files are not collaborating (only coming as read only)

Tags: networking, permissions, samba, libreoffice, sharing

I have shared a folder and files inside  (over a LAN network - Peer to peer). The permissions are for read and write for everyone.

But whenever someone (from a different machine in the same network ) opens the file, it opens as read only file. (These are word and excel files - Libre Writer & Calc).

Post this if any user (from network - for whom file opened in read only) changes it to "Edit Document" and saves the file, it changes its permission to read only for everyone.

My purpose is to provide read and write access to a shared file over the network to multiple users. this is for collaborative work. Any collaborative editing solution for word and excel on local Network is prime requirement

The Permissions for Folder and files are -
drwxrwxrwx and -rwxrw-rw- respectively

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem here are some solutions i had tried.
1> own the parent folder and write permission for all (a+rw *.*), set a incron job for monitoring files getting updated as users makes changes to doc and xls file.

or

2> install winbind libss and install smb4k, mount the parent shared folder through smb4k.  smb4k solves most of the problems in same & cross environment such as ubuntu to ubuntu ,ubuntu to windows ubuntu to mac.